# How to get comments via like-url after "January 2013 Breaking Changes"

Tags: facebook-like

If we disable "January 2013 Breaking Changes" in Apps/Settings/Advanced,
We can get comment via like-url.

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time \
FROM comment \
WHERE object_id IN \
  (SELECT comments_fbid \
   FROM link_stat \
   WHERE url ='http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/')
```

But, if we enable it, I cannot get comments_fbid from link_stat.

So, my question is how to get comments via like-url after the "January 2013 Breaking Changes"?